# Get Availability from a booking system

Tags: postgresql

In the last days I saw many topics to solve this problem but I did not found the right answer for my case.

The question is: which rooms are available from a specific date+time to a specific date+time?

I would like to add my 2 cents for the solution I have found, with the hope that can be helpful for others.

I will simplify the example for a postgresql.

You have the list of the rooms in one table:

rooms:

- id
- roomId
- roomName

You have the booking table with the starting and ending date, in my case I used also the time

bookings:

- id
- roomId
- startDate (timestamp)
- endDate (timestamp)

At the end the solution for my case is this:

```
with room_booked as (select distinct(f1.roomId)
      from bookings f1
      where tsrange(f1.startDate, f1.endDate, '[]') && tsrange(<< your start date>>, << your end date >>, '[]'))
      SELECT
        rooms.roomId,
        rooms.roomName
      FROM rooms 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM room_booked
        WHERE room_booked.roomId = rooms.roomId
      )
```

The first with select all the rooms that in some way are included in the range of the date+time to check and in the second not exist you extract the difference from the rooms table.

Of course you can add multiple where in the second one if you need additional requirements.

Thanks

Comment: If you think this answers someone's question better than currently posted solutions, post this as an answer to that question, there. If you want this to be a separate thread where you change that question somehow and then propose a solution to it, edit this to be an actual question, and then post your solution and explanation as an actual answer below.

Comment: My question is with this `f1.startDate, f1.endDate, '[]') && tsrange(<< your start date>>, << your end date >>, '[]')`. For a sufficiently large `<< your start date>>, << your end date >>,` that could cover periods where the room is actually available.

Comment: It would make more sense to ask for both the desired duration of the stay as well as the range of interest, e.g. 1 week stay, anytime in February. For specific dates you can make these equal: rooms available for 3 days, in a range of just those specific 3 days. Right now, this only finds rooms available for the entire time in that range, so just the 2nd case. Used for finding rooms available for any duration within the range, this currently does filter things out against intention.

Comment: Do yourself a (big) favor and use as tsrange datatype in the bookings-table for the combination, instead of two different columns like you have right now. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Comment: @FrankHeikens, not necessarily a favor for the following reasons a) Clients that don't understand range types. b) Even for client that understand range types you generally end up splitting the range into individual elements in a form and then recombining them into a range.  I have found it  easier just to do that on the individual columns behind the scenes in the query that does the comparison.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver When a client is not familiar with the range data types, it's up to you and me to explain. My experience is that most/all programmers love to learn something new. And yes, from the GUI you most likely get two inputs, the start and the end. Functions like daterange() or tsrange() take care of that. And for hotel and meeting room reservations you need a date but also a time. Especially for late checkout or an early checkin. Functionality like that is so easy to implement/support using ranges, it always works and you will never have booking conflicts.

Comment: 1) I should have been more specific, when I said client I was referring to client library. 2) I am not discounting range types. I am just saying as a practical matter two columns will often make it easier to move data to and from the client. Then leave it to the back end to make a range type out of them for comparison sake.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Recently I had to work with an ORM, SQLAlchemy, and I was pleasantly surprised with the support for many data types, including ranges: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html